# <href=link> autofill username and password

Tags: authentication, passwords, href

I have a link button to open a link containing a webpage that needs user name and password to access. Is there anyway when the user opens the link the username and password will fill automatically? It's inside a secure network.

Comment: *Maybe*?  You can put values on your URLs.  What the target of the URL does with those values is up to the code at that target.  There isn't nearly enough information here to provide any sort of solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please do before asking question.

Comment: <a href="https://hcr" class="myButton" target="_blank">System</a>

Comment: TD><input name="txtUsername" type="text" maxlength="15" id="txtUsername" style="width:193px;" /></TD> <TD><input name="txtPassword" type="password" maxlength="15" id="txtPassword" style="width:193px;" /></TD>